# Rails: error with pjax "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pjax' "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pjax

Gemfile:

> gem 'pjax_rails'

app/assests/javascripts/application.js :

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require_tree . 
//= require jquery.pjax


$(function() {
 $('a').pjax('[data-pjax-container]');
});
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<div id="data-pjax-container" data-pjax-container>
        <%= yield %>
</div>
```

The error i'm getting in chrome is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pjax'

And it refers to the application.js file. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could change you imports to:

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require jquery.pjax
//= require_tree .
```

I also do believe that you should bind it in your ready event, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a').pjax('[data-pjax-container]');
});
```

Hope it helps